# get screenshot of the page using selenium and requests

Tags: python, selenium, python-requests, xmlhttprequest

i need to get screenshot of the page. Site https://kad.arbitr.ru/ blocked selenium. After pressing the search button site do nothing. In inspector i see POST request using XHR. How can i execute POST request at this site? Sorry for stupid question, im newbie in Python. Maybe you can suggest other solution

```
fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
options = Options()
#options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'FILES\\geckodriver.exe', firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get('https://kad.arbitr.ru/')

#pickle.dump( driver.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb")) #Cookies
#response = webdriver.request('POST', 'https://kad.arbitr.ru/Kad/SearchInstances')
#print(response)

for request in driver.requests:
    if request.response:
        print(
            request.url,
            request.response.status_code,
            request.response.headers['Content-Type']
        )
```

Comment: Please show us your code, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can read more in the first link in google: [web](https://www.browserstack.com/guide/take-screenshot-with-selenium-python)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
from Screenshot import Screenshot_Clipping

fp = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
options = Options()  # I don't know what is it in your code
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options, executable_path=r'FILES\\geckodriver.exe', firefox_profile=fp)
driver.get('https://kad.arbitr.ru/')
driver.save_screenshot('ss.png')  # this is the answer

screenshot = Image.open('ss.png')
screenshot.show()

ss = Screenshot_Clipping.Screenshot()  # another method
image = ss.full_Screenshot(driver, save_path=r'.' , image_name='name.png')
```

Comment: You copy-pasted without trying it I guess, the imports should be   
`from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options`

Comment: There is no matter am I trying or not; I know that selenium has "save_screenshot" method, but I don't know for what Ruslan uses "options()". And I just wrote those libraries that indeed to save screenshot, assume that others has already imported

Comment: But you're not using nor Image nor Screenshot_clipping .-. 
And following what you wrote you wouldn't have imported `from selenium import webdriver` assuming that was already imported lol

Comment: My fault, updated the answer.

Comment: Also (excuse me if I am too fussy), you imported `Screenshot_clipping` with lowercase 'c' and then you use `Screenshot_Clipping` with capital 'c', which is the correct one? And `‘ss.png‘` should have ' or " instead of backticks

Comment: I hope you're happy now

Comment: Yes, I will upvote your answer now :D

Comment: Ah, last note for Ruslan: PIL has become pillow. So to use it you will need to `pip3 install pillow`.

Answer (score 1):

You can take screenshots in a simple way: using `driver.save_screenshot('screenshot.png')`

Answer (score 0):

You can take a screenshot with selenium pretty easily:

```py
driver.save_screenshot("image.png")
```

This question is so popular, there are dozens of APIs dedicated to taking screenshots of a webpage. You can find them out by doing a Google search.